# Live collaboration with another person on the same .py file?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, collaboration

I am trying to work on the same `.py` file as my friend. I am looking for the Google Docs of coding (being able to see each other's changes live). How can I do it? Is there a plugin for PyCharm or Sublime Text 3 (preferably Sublime)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vs code for that.
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/11/15/live-share